# URL that launches NewQuote dialog in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, urlhacking, quote

In Classic, I can launch the NewQuote dialog using an URL like so:

```
let url = "/0Q0/e?nooverride=1&oppid=0060900000NKZXQ&retURL=%2F0060900000NKZXQ";
window.location.assign(url);
```

Note that this code brings the dialog up with certain fields (Account, Pricebook, CurrencyIsoCode) pre-populated from the Opportunity and on Save the Opportunity's line items are copied to the new Quote - everything works just like the standard NewQuote button.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Lightning? I am thinking of something like

```
let url = "/lightning/o/Quote/new?...";
sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
```

My plan is to override the NewQuote action button with a VF page that adds parameters (URL Hack) which pre-populate a number of custom fields before launching the standard NewQuote dialog.

**Clarification**

My problem is *not* (or not yet) the URL-Hack; the question is how to get Lightning to do the same thing it does when I click the built-in (not yet overridden) New Quote button in the Quotes related list.

What I did so far (and where I am stuck) is:

1. I click the New Quote button (not overridden!); this brings up the New Quote dialog.
2. I copy the URL that is displayed; it looks like this:
   `https://myorg-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Quote/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&uid=166370128014080937&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FOpportunity%2F0060900000NKZXQAA5%2Fview`
3. I leave the New Quote dialog by pressing Cancel.
4. I paste the previously copied URL into the search bar at the top and press enter. The New Quote entry form displays - but the Opportunity lookup field is not initialised and I get an error when I click Save.
5. I make the problem go away by adding `&defaultFieldValues=OpportunityId%3D0060900000NKZXQAA5`; when I now save, no error is thrown, a Quote is created, but the line items are not copied.

Exactly the same thing happens when I redirect from my VF page using the `sforce.one.navigateToURL()` call shown above: when I explicitly set the OpportunityId I can save the new Quote, *but the line items are not copied*.

In conclusion, it appears that not everything that can be done in Classic can be done with the same ease in Lightning Experience.

BTW: I know I can just create a VF Page that does the entire work up to and including the creation of the line items; but this last thing is what I hoped to be able to avoid - it just feels stupid to have to reverse engineer a functionality available out of the box *and* losing the flexibility offered by the user modifiable page layout into the bargain.

Comment: see https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/

Comment: cropredy: see edits added at the bottom of my post